# Criterion for Smoothness of a Function Mapping Into an Exterior Power of a Vector Space.

Tags: smooth-manifolds, exterior-algebra

All vector spaces are assumed to be real and finite dimensional.

I am trying to show that:

> Let $V$ be a vector space and $f:\bigoplus^k V\to \bigwedge^k V$ be defined as $$f(v_1, \ldots, v_k)= v_1\wedge \cdots\wedge v_k$$
>   Then $f$ is smooth.

In general, I am looking for a criterion for smoothness of a map $f:M\to \bigwedge^k V$ from a smooth manifold $M$ into the exterior power of a vector space.

For example, a map $f:M\to V$ is smooth if and only if $\omega\circ f:M\to \mathbf R$ is smooth for all $\omega\in V^*$.

Thanks.

Comment: On finite-dimensional spaces, multilinear maps are always smooth (analytic even), when you write them in bases, all components are (homogeneous) polynomials in the coefficients. Since $\bigwedge^k V$ is a finite-dimensional space, the criterion with the linear forms holds.

Comment: Ah! The map is multilinear! Thanks.